# Swagger adds controller's private fields as body parameters of the requests

Tags: java, resteasy, swagger

We have a simple controller with dao and GET endpoint:

```
@Api("users")
@Named
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserController {

    private final UserDao userDao;

    @Inject
    public AdController(KeywordsDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @GET
    public Response getUser(@QueryParam("id") int userId) {
        User res = userDao.getUser(userId);
        return Response.ok(res).build();
    }
}

class User {
    @JsonProperty
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Part of the `swagger.json` which demonstrates the problem:

```
...

"paths" : {
    "/users" : {
      "get" : {
        "tags" : [ "users" ],
        "operationId" : "getUsers",
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ 
        {
          "in" : "body",
          "name" : "body",
          "required" : false,
          "schema" : {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/UserDao"
          }
        }, {
          "name" : "userId",
          "in" : "query",
          "required" : false,
          "type" : "integer",
          "format" : "int32"
        } ]
...
```

Any ideas how can I get rid of those "implicit" parameters? They look really confusing in Swagger UI.

General configuration of the project: RESTEasy 3.0.11 + spring-context 3.2.14 + swagger-jaxrs 1.5.4.

Swagger is configured using `BeanConfig` and `ApiListingResource`, which declared in application context:

```
....
<bean class="io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource"/>
<bean id="beanConfig" class="io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
    <property ...
</bean>
....
```

Comment: As long as I remember, the same bug existed in swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.0 and it has been fixed in 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using swagger-jaxrs 1.5.0 instead of 1.5.4. This [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1191) was fixed in 1.5.1.